# Python. Generating a random + or - sign using the random command

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the easiest way to generate a random `+`,`-`,`*`, or `/` sign using the import random function while assigning this to a letter.

E.G.

```
g = answeryougive('+','-')
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 12):

You want [`random.choice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice)

```
random.choice(['+', '-'])
```

Or more concisely:

```
random.choice('+-')
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks i am doing my  GCSE great help

there are several ways to do this but the best is using random.choice for random symbols or random.radiant for numbers Eg.

```
import random
Num1=random.radiant(1,12) #random number one
Num2=random.radiant(1.12) #random number two
sym=random.choice(['+','/','*'.'-']) #random symbol
```

Comment: Add Import statements to your answer.